# R beakr script as Rscript Windows 10 service

Tags: r, windows, service, rscript

I'm trying to setup a simple *beakr* service in Windows that implements the example at https://github.com/MazamaScience/beakr.  I'm able to run the script from the command line successfully and I've been able to add the service in Windows using NSSM, but I am unable to start the service.

When I dig into the service error logs I see that *Rscript.exe* cannot be executed due to a non-specific permissions problem.

My *Rscript.exe* is running out of *C:\Program Files\R<Version>\bin* and my *beakr.R* script is running out of my User home directory.

If anyone has had success implementing a similar service (Web page based REST endpoint) using R in Windows, I would love to know how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to run an R script as Service using [latest pre-release version of NSSM](https://nssm.cc/ci/nssm-2.24-101-g897c7ad.zip) on Windows 10:

1. Create a directory to store the files
   In this example : `C:\R\ServiceTest`
2. Create in this directory a never ending script : `ServiceTest.R`

```
library(beepr)

# Test script : beeps every 10 seconds
while (T) {
  beepr::beep(1)
  if (interactive()) {
    # Shows spin cursor to facilitate test in interactive mode
    for (i in 1:10) {
      if (i%%4==0) {cursor <- '/'}
      if (i%%4==1) {cursor <- '-'}
      if (i%%4==2) {cursor <- '\\'}
      if (i%%4==3) {cursor <- '|'}
      cat('\r',cursor)
      flush.console() 
      Sys.sleep(1)
    } 
  } else {
    Sys.sleep(10)
  }
}
```

I used to let this kind of script run in a console open on my desktop to check various alarms regularly.

3. Create a batch file to run the script : `ServiceTest.bat`

```
Rscript ServiceTest.R
```

4. Open an **Admin** console and make sure the batch file runs correctly:

```
C:\R\ServiceTest>ServiceTest.bat

C:\R\ServiceTest>Rscript ServiceTest.R
 |
```

Cancel the batch (Ctrl+C)

5. Using the **Admin** console, install the batch file as service using NSSM :

```
nssm install
```

[image]

- Set Service name : ServiceTest
- Set Application path : `C:\R\ServiceTest\ServiceTest.bat`
- Set Working directory : `C:\R\ServiceTest\`
- Set Logon : Windows User + Password
- Install Service

6. Open Windows Services Manager, find `ServiceTest` and start it : **if everything went well, that's it!**
7. If you get an error message, check Windows Event Log / Services : you can find there hints on the cause of the problem. Most common problems I encountered :

- error on path
- used local user instead of own user account / password to run the service

8. If you want to remove the service :

```
nssm remove ServiceTest
```

This replaced very nicely the many R consoles I left running in the background on my Desktop.
I see no reasons it wouldn't work with a REST endpoint.

Comment: @laggerratrobe, did you try this solution?